# C# Error CS0052, Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

When I try to compile the following code I get a CS0052 error:

```
struct mp3
{
    public int ID, MBSize;
    public string Make, Model, Price;

    public mp3(int ID, int voorraad, int MBSize, string Make, string Model, string Price)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.MBSize = MBSize;
        this.Make = Make;
        this.Model = Model;
        this.Price = Price;
    }
}

public class Acess
{
    static public List<mp3> mp3List = new List<mp3>();

    static public void laadMP3()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less
>   accessible than field 'SoundSharp___opdracht_3.Acess.mp3List'

Comment: Try using a consistent approach to access modifiers, such as always specifying one (private, protected, public, internal) and always specifying them at the beginning of the line.  This will help to debug problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 6):

The problem I think is that `struct mp3` should be declared as `public` (you have a public `List<mp3>`)

Comment: More specifically, you can't have a public field that aggregates a type of lower accessibility (private is the default). That gives the error.

Comment: @LordTakkera Actually, types can't be `private`. They are either `public` or `internal`. But that's a detail, your point is correct.

Comment: @LordTakkera internal is default for no-nested types.

Comment: That's absolutely right. (A private type wouldn't be much use to anyone, would it)?

Answer (score 2):

`struct`s and `class`es are `internal` by default (unless they are nested within other types, in which case the default is `private`), so you can't use it as a `public` property.  Make the struct `public` and you should be fine:

```
public struct MP3
{
```

Note that I also capitalized `MP3` to follow generally accepted .NET [casing standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).